# event.getSource() returns null on View_Focused using Accessibility in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, accessibility

i am trying to fill `EditText` filed using accessibility service like DashLane  or some other apps which are using accessibility Service. i am using an event view focused. when `EditText` gets focused the event getting started but `getSource()` returns `null`.

Code is:

```
        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

    if (source != null) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "TEST DATA");
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
            Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this, "Pasted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

and i tried some of the other methods which is giving errors. so one question here is why its returning null. can anyone pls help me out.

Comment: can anyone please help me out in this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [event.getSource() returns null Accessibility in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864868/event-getsource-returns-null-accessibility-in-android)